# Can I set the user agent string of the Ubuntu browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I'm using an M10 tablet and some web sites (e.g. Google drive) put up a warning about the browser being unsupported but essentially work as expected whilst others (looking at you Amazon) simply say the browser is unsupported and deny access.

However I noted that the Kindle cloud reader app in the store has overcome this so I was wondering: Is this done by the user agent string? If so is it available as a browser setting or only programmatically?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/578455/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-in-a-webapp?rq=1