# How can I use the bq ubuntu tablet web browser access mobile website?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webbrowser-app

How can I use the BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu web browser to access mobile websites?

I know flash player is not supported in this device, maybe html5 player can help me to watch a video?

Comment: which site? if they have mobile content, you could posibally create a "web app" which identifies the user agent as mobile, http://askubuntu.com/questions/578455/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-in-a-webapp?rq=1

Comment: thank you for answering my question，maybe it's a good way to access mobile websites.I will try it by changing UA settings.